# Update like Sub query using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this `SQL query` in which there are two tables `tblImages` and `SPEC`.

I am selecting Required column from `tblImages` and after that updating the `SPEC` table

```
update SPEC
    set image1 = isnull((select Image_name
                         from tblimages
                         where orderby = 1 and
                            doc_type=2 and
                            main_ID=@new_ID),
                        'noimage.png')
    where ID=@new_ID
```

How do I convert this query using `Linq to Sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this in single query:

```
var img = db.tblimages.Where(u => u.orderby == 1
                  u.doc_type == 2 && 
                  u.main_ID == @new_ID)
              .Select(u => u.Image_name)
              .FirstOrDefault();

var o = db.SPEC.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == @new_ID);

o.image1 = img != null ? img : "noimage.png"

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Try o.image1 = img ?? "noimage.png"